# How to Update the HttpConfiguration AFTER the Owin TestServer creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

The http configuration is setup in te Startup class usually which is bound to the Create method.

But what if I want to **start** an owin server **ONE time** for ALL tests but **update** its http configuration depending on each test needs?

This is not possible. The server object has nothing useful.

```
using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
{
    var data = server.HttpClient.GetAsync("/api/data);
}
```

What I want to do for CRUD integration tests is stub the service methods

```
// Do it ONE time fall ALL tests
WebApiConfig.Register(config);
WebServicesConfig.Register(config);

// Do it individually for each test, Update DI registerations with Fake components per test method
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var mockContext = new Mock<TGBContext>();
var mockService = new Mock<SchoolyearService>(mockContext.Object); 
mockService.Setup<Task<IEnumerable<SchoolyearDTO>>>(c => c.GetSchoolyearsAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<SchoolyearDTO>()));
// builder.RegisterInstance<TGBContext>(); ****** NO NEED for this it works without registering the ctor parameter dependency 
builder.RegisterInstance<SchoolyearService>(mockService.Object);
builder.Update(((AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver)config.DependencyResolver).Container as IContainer);
```

At the moment I am forced to create a TestServer per Test method.

Thats a total overhead in time.

**SOLUTION**

Make the HttpConfiguration static and this code should work:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var mockContext = new Mock<TGBContext>();
var mockService = new Mock<SchoolyearService>(mockContext.Object);
mockService.Setup<Task<IEnumerable<SchoolyearDTO>>>(c => c.GetSchoolyearsAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<SchoolyearDTO>()));
 builder.RegisterInstance<SchoolyearService>(mockService.Object);
builder.Update(((AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver)Configuration.DependencyResolver).Container as IContainer);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you would like to change for each test?

Comment: I already did... read again above my question. "// Do it individually..." Each test needs to mock different service/repository methods.

Comment: What is your test framework? If it's MSTest, (1) you can get name of the test will be executed in TestInitialize method then (2) based on the TestName we can decide which need to be mocked then (3) create/update the config object. It sounds to work I think.

Comment: @haz What are you talking about? Have you read my question?

Comment: Yes... oh I forget one important point 'start one time' the server. What I wrote is per each test :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to start the OWIN server once for all tests.

1. declare a base class for all your test classes
2. declare a private static readonly variable in your base class for the OWIN Server.

`private static readonly TestServer _webServer = TestServer.Create<Startup>();`

3. declare a protected static variable to expose this server to all the tests.

`protected static TestServer WebServer { get { return _webServer; } }`

this should solve your problem of instantiating the web server only once for all the test runs. and if you don't want to initialize the web server so early, you can use lazy instantiation etc. but the point is to make it static and initialize it at definition time itself, so that it is once per app domain.

as for getting access to the HttpConfiguration in your unit tests.. here is one possible way..

1. in your Startup.cs, declare a public property...

`public static HttpConfiguration HttpConfiguration { get; private set; }`

2. initialize this variable in the configure method of the Startup.cs class.

   ```
       HttpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
       HttpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

       // do more stuff.. setting resolver etc.
       // and then finally

       app.UseWebApi(HttpConfiguration);
   ```
3. This HttpConfiguration property is your web api's configuration and because we made it a public property, it should be accessible in your test project and to all tests.

   ```
       Startup.HttpConfiguration
   ```

you can access it to modify the dependency resolver definitions etc.

```
        Startup.HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver
```

please note that you can update the DependencyResolver definitions even after you initialize the web server... the updated definitions will still have their effect.

4. if you're concerned about your HttpConfiguration just publicly available, then make the Startup class internal and make it visible only to your unit test project.

Comment: I am more concerned that I have to make things public/static to please my tests. I would prefer when the Owin Team would make TestServer.HttpConfiguration because the TestServer  anyway consumes the Startup class. But yes your advise should work combined with my code above "// Do it individually for each test, Update DI registerations with Fake components per test method" :-)

Comment: i hear your concern Elisa.. and internal modifier (with InternalsVisibleTo) was the only viable option i could think of to reduce the surface area of exposure..

Comment: After my holidays ;-) I had time to implement it now. And there is one learning. Create a TestServer is TWO miliseconds. So no need to care for because cleaning up the testserver after all class tests did not work, the attribute was just not triggered. So I just use your public HttpConfiguration  hint ;-)